# iOS - Take image using AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to take picture with AVCaptureSession for iOS, I can take a picture but it takes like a print screen and save it on PhotoLibrary, How can I get real picture not print screen and also save it on view not in a library, would you please help me in this implementation,

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
- (void) scanButtonPressed {

CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();(what should I use here instead of 
UIGetScreenImage)
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
CGImageRelease(screen);


// Save the captured image to photo album
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,   
@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void
*)contextInfo
{
UIAlertView *alert;

if (error)
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                       message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
else {
CoverCapturePhoto *c = [[CoverCapturePhoto alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
    [c.captureImage setImage:image];
}

[alert show];
}
```

Comment: Do you actually mean using the camera, or taking a screen grab but not using private API??

Comment: @Wain using the camera and take a photo and show it to the other screen

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate and use `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. Apple supplies [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) showing how to take an image with the camera.

You are explicitly saving the image with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` - you don't need to do that. Just use the `image` in an image view or similar.

---

Or if I misunderstood, see [How to take a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically).

Comment: no I don't need screenshot, but how to save my image on imageView?