# Take screenshot of screen (iOS app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, screenshot

I'm working on an application and I want to take the instant screenshot of my screen. I read some tutorials about that, and found this sort of solutions :

```
UIImageView * Test = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[self.view layer] renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
Test.image = screenShot;
[self.view addSubview:Test];
```

But this code doesn't give me the same thing as when on your device you push home and the other button to make a screenshot. How could i fix it please ?

EDIT : I have included QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically

Comment: It doesn't do an exact screenshot as you could get by pushing home and the other button

Comment: What's different between the two screenshots? What components are on your screen?

Comment: FYI - don't hardcode the screen size and scale. Your code is only valid for a non-retina, 3.5" iPhone/iPod touch.

Comment: The difference is that i have a cube in 3D, done with CALayers, and i have only the initial view onto the screenshot even if i have put : [[self.view.layer presentationLayer] renderInContext:context];  It doesn't take in count rotations etc