# Sharing Screen Shot to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, screenshot, posting

I have the following code to post to Facebook for my app;

This is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>

@interface LifeTipsViewController : UIViewController {
    SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;
}

  -(IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender;

@end
```

and the .m file (Facebook posting code)

```
-(IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender {
    mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController
    composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"hi"];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

I want to be able to press the 'Share' button and the app to get a screen shot of the current view to post to Facebook. What code would need to be added to this Facebook posting code to allow it to share a screen shot of the app?
Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

```
-(IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender {
    mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController
    composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"hi"];


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
    [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [mySLComposerSheet addImage:image];


    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work blame https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SLComposeViewController/addImage: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically but if it does, you should really learn to use Google. That is all I did.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it when I get home. Had googled and tried a lot of things so turned to writing my own question. Didn't see the code you posted come up.