# Is it possible to send class name and screenshot of the view when unexceptional handling error occurs to server iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, server

I can able send only the unexceptional handling to server when app is crashed But I am not able to send the viewController's name and screenshot of the view controller to server.Is it possible to send those two to server?Can anyone please provide me some information regarding this?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You may need to read about uncaught exceptions https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Concepts/UncaughtExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000056-BAJDDGGD and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically .

Comment: I took the screenshot also but how to send to server when app is crashed