# Is it possible to capture the screen of an iPhone programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

I am not sure that Apple allows this kind of stuff. I just want to make an application to take a screen capture whatever app is open on the iPhone **not only the current application**. Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: You can capture the things which are on a `UIView` but you can't capture which are on a `UIWindow`. For ex: If you have a `UIAlertView` presented, that won't be captured but other subviews of UIView will be

Comment: that means i can capture the things which on my application screen. except i can not do any thing on My UIWindow of iphone.

Comment: You cant capture Navigation Bar and all elements which are presented on UIWindow like AlertView, ActionSheet etc.

Comment: Also you can't capture any other app's screen

Comment: Ya Thanx dear Rajan.

Answer (score 0):

No, afraid not. Due to sandboxing, you only have access to your own app's window.

Answer (score 0):

`You can't capture screen of another applications or windows rather then your application. It's restricted by apple.`

You can capture your application's screen by using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. for that you can refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically).

Comment: We can't capture any objects that are on UIWindow like `UIAlertView` or you can say `UIAlertController`

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari : Yeah!! right, i have already mentioned that in answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can find all information about background tasks here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html
But I don't think, that Apple will allow you to take screenshots of other apps, as it could lead to security problems.

Answer (score -2):

You can't capture other applications screen except your own application.  Here is the code to take screen shot of the view

```
class Welcome: UIViewController {

       if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

       [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
       UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);

}
```