# Save Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement to a bitmap image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to render a VisualElement as an image?

I'd like to save screenshots of some of my UI's elements in my Xamarin.Forms application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. **Xamarin** does not have that kind of feature. You should write a `Renderer` for your UIComponent.

Fortunately there is an [Objective-C iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically) implementation, and an [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android) one as well. You can inspire from them.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a library](https://github.com/dimonovdd/ImageFromXamarinUI) to take partial screenshot.