# From gps locations to maps

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a question to ask.
In my app, I have collected user location from GPS. I have also used Google Maps to show this location on a map.
What I need now is to save a picture on this location on my map and post it on Facebook. More or less the same thing Runtastic does.
Can someone help me doing this?
I have GPS location, then I have to build a map using Google Maps Api, then take a picture of it and post it on Facebook as a link, for example.
I hope this is clear enough for you.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a screenshot of the screen using the [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203293/4019540). In `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` you can set the `rect` of the Google Maps window.

Using the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios) you can share the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for taking a screenshot of a particular view

> **Swift 3.x code**

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mapView.frame.size)
 self.mapView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
 let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

 // I used this on a imageView
 imageView.image = image
```

My `imageView` is just above the button.

Check my output 
[image]