# Programatically taken screenshot returning blank image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, screenshot, uialertview

I have to take a screenshot on tapping on **"ok"** button of *UIAlertView*. And the screenshot should contain the alertview and all the other views present on the device screen. I tried to implement the functionality of screenshot capturing using below code. But the screenshot that I have taken is giving a blank image.
Please give a solution for this issue.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  keyWindow] ;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 704);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);

[keyWindow.rootViewController.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:keyWindow.rootViewController.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShotImage);

 [fileManager createFileAtPath:@"/Users/mac/Desktop/myimage.png" contents:myImageData attributes:nil];
```

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/2203293/4831524

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)