# UILabel not showing in screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

In an attempt to capture a screenshot, everything but the UILabels is being captured. I've checked the view hierarchy to see if the labels were being hidden somehow but everything looks fine.

By the way, I am happy that the navigation controller is hidden in the screenshot, I just need to figure out why the labels are hidden.

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
@IBAction func cameraBarButtonItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

  guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    print("No Graphics Context")
    return
  }

  view.layer.render(in: context)

  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  print("Photo Screen Captured")

  guard let photoImage = image else {
    return
  }

  guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImage, 1.0) else {
    return
  }

  userQueue.async {

    savePhotoToPhotoLibrary(data: imageData) {

    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: make sure the label is subview to uiview

Comment: @KishoreKumar i've added an image of the hierarchy. Wouldn't the label that is a subview of a stackview constitute it as being a subview of the main view.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

  guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    print("No Graphics Context")
    return
  }

  view.layer.render(in: context)
```

Make sure the UILabel is a subview of the view that you are using for the screenshot.

Otherwise, use [this code from another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203293/5105555) to take a screenshot of the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

The method that seems to do the trick is:

```
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```